# Vuetify date picker not working on the production build

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I've a date picker component like this

```
<v-date-picker v-model="date" range landscape></v-date-picker>
```

and this is modeled to the **date** `array`. Which is work fine when I run the project localy.

Once I build the project in the production I got these errors

> TypeError: t.split is not a function or its return value is not
>   iterable
>
> TypeError: Cannot set property 'isDark' of undefined
>
> TypeError: this.lastValue.split is not a function
>
> TypeError: t.trim is not a function

**and a warning says**

> Value must be a String, got Array

[image]

Any idea why this happen only in the production (npm build) and works fine in the dev (npm serve)

Comment: hi, did you get the solution for this? I'm facing this issue too, please help

Answer (score 0):

This problem stems from previous versions of vuetify, just upgrade to a recent version of [Vuetify](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify) to fix the problem.